# TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined at socket.handshake

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, socket.io, authorize

I am trying to rebuild the socket.io code from 0.9v to 1.x. 
Express and socket.io are last versions.

So, the error: `Cannot call method 'get' of undefined` at

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
            console.log(socket.handshake);
            var username = socket.handshake.user.get('username'); //<----here

            ......
```

This is my code:

```
module.exports = function(server) {
                var io = require('socket.io')(server);
                io.set('origins', 'localhost:*');
            //I changed set to use, but it's doesn't matter i think
                io.use(function(socket, next) {  
                    var handshake = socket.request;
                //io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
                    async.waterfall([
                        function(callback) {
                         handshake.cookies = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie || '');

     var sidCookie = handshake.cookies[config.get('session:key')];
      var sid = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(sidCookie, config.get('session:secret'));
      //var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(sidCookie, config.get('session:secret'));

                            loadSession(sid, callback);
                        },  ...continue...
```

continuation:

```
function(session, callback) {

                            if (!session) {
                                callback(new HttpError(401, "No session"));
                            }

                            handshake.session = session;
                            loadUser(session, callback);
                        },
                        function(user, callback) {
                            if (!user) {
                                callback(new HttpError(403, "Anonymous session may not connect"));
                            }

                            handshake.user = user;
                            callback(null);
                        }

                    ], function(err) {.....});
                next();
                });

        io.on('connection', function(socket) { ... };
```

return io;
};

Ok, help me please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How I would debug this.
**Can't call a method on something undefined**

So we know that whatever is calling .get has not been created yet. In this case:

```
var username = socket.handshake.user.get('username'); //<----here
```

So the first thing I'd do if you don't have access to an ide debugger is

console.log(sockets)

**if that has data**

console.log(socket.handshake);

**If that has data**

console.log(socket.handshake.user);

If that has data check that it has the method GET.

Anyways, My assumption is that `socket.handshake.user` hasn't been defined yet. 
Where is the code that sets this up/exposes it?

Comment: ok. I checked in console debugger "socket.handshake" - it has some data, but socket.handshake.user has nothing (no error, just new string). And socket.handshake.user.get - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

Comment: Where is the code that sets this up/exposes it?
- in `function(user, callback) { handshake.user = user; callback(null); }`

Comment: Ok. In `function (user, callback){...}` after `handshake.user = user` we have `handshake.user.username = "correct username"`.
And now, I need to correctly set `var username` in `io.on('connection', function(socket) {`
Help me!

Comment: So I can see you set up user.username, but you don't set up the .get method, maybe I need to take a look at the socket methods, but if you personally set up the user object then you will need to set up the get function

Comment: YOu could do this to show what i mean handshake.user.username.get = (function(data){ console.log('hello' , data)});`

Comment: What that will do is, whenever you call get it will execute that function, so perhaps somewhere in the framework is something that tells you how to set up the .get function for user.username?

Comment: " Where is the code that sets this up/exposes it? - in function(user, callback) { handshake.user = user; callback(null); "

So where does the 'user' come from? (the one you use to set up handshake.user) console log(user);

Comment: So where does the user come from? - from:
`function loadUser(session, callback) {
User.findById(session.user, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (!user) {
            return callback(null, null);}
        callback(null, user);
    });
}
`                     So, this returns user from database

Comment: Ok so the problem isn't this code, it is what sets up that user data, I'm assuming the username for each user is set up somewhere, like so:

`io.socket.set('username', 'Guest');`